# Angularjs: is it possible to store persistant data into directive isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to store data to local isolated scope in order to speed up things, and access stored data from isolated scope method.

Unfortunately, I get null as returned value for scope.scroller.scrollLeft().

Also is it possible to update ng-show="canNext()" in a more efficient way than I did?

```
app.directive("photos", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            "photoid": "@",
            "size": "@",
            "height": "@",
            "list": "=",
            "prefix":"@",
            "suffix":"@",
            "extension": "@",
            "class": "@",
            "slide": "="
        },
        template: 
        '<div id="photos{{photoid}}Container"\n\
            style="position:relative"\n\
            ng-style="{display:list.length==1?\'inline-block\':\'block\', width: list.length==1?\'{{size||\'171px\'}}\':\'auto\', height: \'{{height||size||\'auto\'}}\'}">\n\
            <div id="photos{{photoid}}"\n\
                class="scroller hScrollable"\n\
                nng-class="doesScroll()&&\'hScrollable\'">\n\
                <div ng-repeat="p in list"\n\
                    ng-style="{\'background-image\': \'url({{prefix}}{{p.path?p.path+\'/\':\'\'}}{{p.file}}{{suffix}}.{{extension||\'jpg\'}})\', width: \'{{size||\'171px\'}}\', height: \'{{height||size||\'171px\'}}\'}"\n\
                    ng-click="$parent.$parent.openPopoverImageViewer(\'#photos{{photoid}}\', {{$index}})">\n\
                    <div>{{p.text||p.description}}</div>\n\
                </div>\n\
            </div>\n\
            <div class="prev" ng-if="list.length>1" ng-show="canPrev()" ng-click="left()"></div>\n\
            <div class="next" ng-if="list.length>1" ng-show="canNext()" ng-click="right()"></div>\n\
        </div>',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            scope.slide         = scope.slide||0;
            scope.prefix        = scope.prefix||"";
            scope.suffix        = scope.suffix||"";
            scope.extension     = scope.extension||"jpg";
            scope.scroller      = $("#photos"+scope.photoid);
            console.log("scope : "+scope.scroller);

            scope.scrollerWidth = scope.scroller.width();
            scope.width         = scope.list.length*(4+(scope.size||171));
            console.log("scope width: "+scope.width);

            scope.canPrev = function() {
                console.log("scope : "+scope.scroller+" - scrollLeft="+scope.scroller.scrollLeft());
                var scroller = $("#photos"+scope.photoid);
                return scroller.scrollLeft();
            };
        scope.right = function() {
            //console.log("scope.photos: right()");
            var scroller = $("#photos"+scope.photoid);
            var l = scope.list.length*(4+(scope.size||171))-scroller.width();
            if (l>0)
            scroller.animate({scrollLeft:l}, 200, function(){
                scope.$apply(scope.canPrev);
                scope.$apply(scope.canNext);
            });
        };
```

Comment: Use a service, store the data there, inject the service into your directive.

Comment: I just had a look at what's a service and it sounds over complex regarding my required purpose. Is that the only solution? What's weird is that what I store in the local shop really exists (I can dump the scrollLeft function for instance) @tymeJV

Comment: storing in service is pretty easy if you create an object instead of multiple variables. A service is also the only way to have persistence

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl and for "Also is it possible to update ng-show="canNext()" in a more efficient way than I did?" any advice?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store and share the data among all the directive instances you can simply use `"this.data = something;"`

If you want to keep data in your instance only (element), you can use your element's data.

```
el.data("key",something);
```

My advice is however to create a "namespace" for your directive as follow:

```
var values = {"key":"value", "key2", "value"};
el.data("yourDirectiveName",values);
```